# How to add Google merchant customer reviews codes on my website

Tags: review, merchant-account

I'm a beginner and need your help.
I am using google listing ads plugin and now I need to add this code to the confirmation order on my website.

https://ibb.co/mybtxfQ

I am using WordPress and woo-commerce with Woodmart theme.

please help me how to add this.

Also I installed google listing ads plugin and sync with my google merchant center account.

Some people zold me that I should add it to thank you page but I added and nothing happened!
I'm a beginner and tell me how can I add this?

Should I change it to another format or I should copy paste to thankyou.php file of my theme ( woodmart ) ???

Please Help Me!

I tried to copy but google didn't accept it.
I have a small business and need help a developer!